# Apache Rewrite Rule

Tags: url-rewriting

I moved a file (file.pdf) from the root of my web directory into a folder called "myfiles". In order to not break existing links and bookmarks, I am looking to setup a rewrite rule so that:

www.domain.tdl/file.pdf will redirect to www.domain.tdl/myfiles/file.pdf

The rewrite rule should work whether you include "www" or not.

Also, my website has a second domain (domain2.tdl). What is the best way to write this rule so that it will work for domain.tdl and domain2.tdl?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use htaccess, this should do:

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+).pdf myfiles/$1.pdf [NC,L]
```

This means that every PDF that is required from the root will be retrieved from the myfiles folder...